# Going to the US and Mexico with two different passports

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, mexico, brazilian-citizens, swedish-citizens

I have two passports, Brazilian and Swedish (dual nationalities). I am flying from Brazil to the US  (Miami) and would like to use my Swedish passport with approved ESTA. During my vacation in the US (16 days) I will fly to Mexico (Cancun for 8 days) and would like to know if I can leave the US and enter Mexico with my Brazilian passport (Brazilians don't need a Visa to enter MEX). When flying back from Cancun to the US (Miami) can I enter with my Swedish passport again?

My concern is:

- I will enter the US with my Swedish passport (valid ESTA), and from the US fly to MEX with my Brazilian passport. Is that ok?
- Can I leave the US with my Brazilian passport (which doesn't have a valid US visa) to enter MEX?
- I will enter MEX with my Brazilian passport (no visa required), and from MEX fly to the US with my Swedish passport (valid ESTA). Is that OK?
- When I return to the US the second time, will I have a “departure stamp” or will the officer only see one “entry stamp”?

Comment: [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) might shed some light on how to travel using two passports.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter Mexico visa free with a Swedish passport. Anyone with even a Schengen visa can enter Mexico without a visa. All of the things you've suggested would probably be OK too. The US doesn't stamp on departure, but receives departure information from airlines. Therefore, you should always give the airline the  passport details for the passport you showed at the US border, or the US could believe you are overstaying. The same should hold true in Mexico. Give the airline you leave Mexico with the passport details for the passport you showed at the Mexican border. In your case, it might be simpler just to use your Swedish passport, since it will prevent any kind of confusion.

Comment: "always give the airline the passport details for the passport you showed at the US border, or the US could believe you are overstaying": for a short trip to Mexico followed by a departure using the Swedish passport, within the original 90-day period of admission, this probably wouldn't matter too much.  On re-entry, the officer might notice the unmatched record of the previous entry, but since it's within 90 days, there's no problem.  If the officer says anything, a simple explanation should suffice.  But I agree that using the Swedish passport throughout is simpler.

Comment: @phoog Yeah I know that it actually doesn't matter in this specific case because a trip to Mexico wouldn't reset the clock anyway, but if OP ended up departing from Mexico back to Brazil for some reason, they would need to manually correct their departure record if they use different passports.

Comment: Good point.  I often forget about the possibility of having to change travel plans.

Comment: Hi and thanks for all the help! My swedish passport is only valid until May this year and I dont have the time to go back to Sweden and renew it. When traveling to the US with my swedish passport it doesn't matter that the date of expiry is less than 6 months away, but I red that when going to Mexico it has to be valid for at least 6 month. Hence, I was thinking that I should use my brazilian passport for Mexico (valid until 2020).